# Block type error

Tags: magento-1.7, cms, page-content

I accidentally removed a space then suddenly the code below became 1 line spacing instead of 0 and I can't bring it back.

```
{{block type="bannerslider/default" name="bannerslider.bannerslider" template="bannerslider/bannerslider.phtml" bannerslider_id="2"}}
{{block type="bannerslider/default" name="bannerslider.bannerslider" template="bannerslider/bannerslider.phtml" bannerslider_id="3"}}
{{block type="promotion/event" name="site.event.siderbar" template="site/event/sidebar.phtml"}}
```

became like this:

```
{{block type="bannerslider/default" name="bannerslider.bannerslider" template="bannerslider/bannerslider.phtml" bannerslider_id="2"}}

{{block type="bannerslider/default" name="bannerslider.bannerslider" template="bannerslider/bannerslider.phtml" bannerslider_id="3"}}

{{block type="promotion/event" name="bluechip.event.siderbar" template="bluechip/event/sidebar.phtml"}}
```

Banner sliders are not on the right side anymore. Please help as I'm not an expert. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where was this code? In a CMS page? What version of Magento?

Comment: Hi. Have you checked with enable template path hints? Or Have you check slider is created on admin side or not? Thanks.

Comment: @Haim Yes in a CMS page and Magento 1.7

Comment: @Raj How can I enable template path hints? I can't access local file only thru the magento dasboard..

Comment: @mark to be clear, are you putting this in the code editor view of the WYSIWYG editor?

Comment: @Mark. Go to admin>System>Configuration>Select your store>Developer>Debug where you can find Template Path Hints.

Comment: @Haim note sure what WYSIWYG is, i'm afraid.. but i'm editing that on the cms page>content editor

Comment: @Raj I can only see under Developer>Debug>Profiler and the option is yes or no only

Comment: @Mark. You have to select "Current Configuration Scope:" to store view from left above corner side for show template path hints option.

Answer (score 0):

When you're editing your CMS page, use  the **show/hide editor** button to go into code editor mode.

Once you're in the code editor, paste in your code and then save your page.
[image]

Comment: this is the code showing

Comment: Did you click on that button? That's where the code belongs

Comment: Yes I did but the 3 codes above i provided still under the below section and it should be at the right side..

Comment: Can you update your question and paste the entire content of the CMS page from the code view? I'm not understanding what's wrong or what you're asking

Answer (score 0):

[image: homepage]

```
<div class="col-main-index">
<div class="slide-banner">{{block type="bannerslider/default" name="bannerslider.bannerslider" template="bannerslider/bannerslider.phtml" bannerslider_id="6"}}</div>     
 <div class="box-banner">    
 <h2><span style="color: #333333;">VIDEOS</span></h2>     
</div>    
<p>{{block type="bannerslider/default" name="bannerslider.bannerslider" template="bannerslider/bannerslider.phtml" bannerslider_id="2"}}</p>    
<p>{{block type="bannerslider/default" name="bannerslider.bannerslider" template="bannerslider/bannerslider.phtml" bannerslider_id="3"}}</p>    
<p>{{block type="promotion/event" name="bluechip.event.siderbar" template="bluechip/event/sidebar.phtml"}}</p>    
<p>{{widget type="cms/widget_block" template="cms/widget/static_block/default.phtml" block_id="9"}}</p>    
</div>
```

Comment: maybe somewhere in the code when i accidentally removed a space the division affected it

Comment: @Haim which tag should I need to use in order to go back to the right side as tag became <p> (paragraph).